# Como guardar un common table expressions (CTE) a una variable en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy intentando guardar el valor de un common table expressions (CTE) en una variable declarada.

Esto es todo lo que tengo.

```
DECLARE @valor decimal(12,0)

with xc as ( 
                                     select v.productoid, p.nombre, eq.unidadid, eq.FactorConversion, sum(v.cantidad) as cantidad
                                     from ventas as v
                                         inner join productos as p on p.id = v.productoid
                                         left join unidades as u on u.id = p.unidadid
                                         left join equivalencias as eq on eq.unidadid = v.unidadid
                                     where v.productoid = 1270
                                     group by v.productoid, p.nombre, eq.unidadid, eq.FactorConversion

                            ) select ( cantidad * FactorConversion ) as Cantidad
                            from xc inner join (
                                            select p.id, p.nombre, p.pesomililitros from productos as p where p.id = 1270 
                            ) as x1
                on x1.id = productoid
select @valor = Cantidad from xc
```

Al ejecutarlo me indica esto:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid object name 'xc'.
```

Al parecer no reconoce el objeto `xc`. 
El valor que obtiene la CTE es

```
700.000
```

Ese valor quiero guardarlo en mi variable `@valor`
 si solo ejecuto.. esto..

```
with xc as ( 
                                     select v.productoid, p.nombre, eq.unidadid, eq.FactorConversion, sum(v.cantidad) as cantidad
                                     from ventas as v
                                         inner join productos as p on p.id = v.productoid
                                         left join unidades as u on u.id = p.unidadid
                                         left join equivalencias as eq on eq.unidadid = v.unidadid
                                     where v.productoid = 1270
                                     group by v.productoid, p.nombre, eq.unidadid, eq.FactorConversion

                            ) select ( cantidad * FactorConversion ) as Cantidad
                            from xc inner join (
                                            select p.id, p.nombre, p.pesomililitros from productos as p where p.id = 1270 
                            ) as x1
                on x1.id = productoid
```

Espero que alguien me oriente.
gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hola que tal JuanL que te pareceria probar de la siguiente manera.

```
;with xc as ( 
    select v.productoid, p.nombre, eq.unidadid, eq.FactorConversion, sum(v.cantidad) as cantidad
    from ventas as v
         inner join productos as p on p.id = v.productoid
         left join unidades as u on u.id = p.unidadid
         left join equivalencias as eq on eq.unidadid = v.unidadid
    where v.productoid = 1270
    group by v.productoid, p.nombre, eq.unidadid, eq.FactorConversion

), px as (

    select p.id, 
           p.nombre, 
           p.pesomililitros 
    from 
           productos as p 
    where 
           p.id = 1270 
)



select 
    @valor = (xc.cantidad*xc.FactorConversion)
from xc 
    inner join px as x1 on x1.id = xc.productoid
```

Te comento puedes usar diversos CTE's solo es necesario separarlos por una coma al termino de cada CTE y cuando termines de declarar tus CTE's necesarios despues puedes hacer joins entre los mismos o jugar con ellos como mejor te parezca, espero que esto te ayude, saludos.